# Marker throwing error while adding, How to resolve this?

Tags: android, here-api

I am trying to add a photo marker using here sdk but it is throwing an error of null point i dont understand why is it a null pointer error or a code error??

Directory image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7J4v.jpg

```
 private void loadMapScene() {
        // Load a scene from the SDK to render the map with a map style.
        mapView.getMapScene().loadScene(MapStyle.NORMAL_DAY, new MapScene.LoadSceneCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadScene(@Nullable MapScene.ErrorCode errorCode) {
                if (errorCode == null) {
                    mapView.getCamera().setTarget(new GeoCoordinates(17.3850, 78.4867));
                    mapView.getCamera().setZoomLevel(14);

                    GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates= new GeoCoordinates(17.3850, 78.4867);

                    MapImage mapImage = MapImageFactory.fromResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.here_car);

                    MapMarker mapMarker = new MapMarker(geoCoordinates);
                    mapMarker.addImage(mapImage, new MapMarkerImageStyle());

                    mapView.getMapScene().addMapMarker(mapMarker);



                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onLoadScene failed: " + errorCode.toString());
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

Edit 1
Error :

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
W/System.err:     at com.example.death.MainActivity$7.onLoadScene(MainActivity.java:272)
        at com.here.sdk.core.threading.RunnableImpl.run(Native Method)
        at com.here.sdk.core.threading.MainThreadTaskRunner.a(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.here.sdk.core.threading.MainThreadTaskRunner.lambda$93nD-I9pqERpDgqXkXMj7C0moag(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.here.sdk.core.threading.-$$Lambda$MainThreadTaskRunner$93nD-I9pqERpDgqXkXMj7C0moag.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of your error

Answer (score 1):

It seems you missed to set the `context`. Try this to provide a context:

```
Context context = MainActivity.this;
Resources resources = context.getResources();
MapImage mapImage = MapImageFactory.fromResource(resources, R.drawable.here_car);
```

Your stack trace indicates that you are executing this from your main activity. First line indicates that `context` is null.

The context is required by Android to access the application's resources folder(s). There's also some working [example code](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/master/examples/android/MapMarker/app/src/main/java/com/here/mapmarker/MapMarkerExample.java) available on GitHub that shows how to load an image with the HERE SDK (Lite Edition). As `context` the `Activity` instance is used (like above).

Answer (score -2):

Try to add image as marker like this :

```
BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.her_car)

MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
         .title("Current Location")
         .snippet("")
         .icon(icon);

mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

hope this will help!

Comment: Question relates to HERE SDK for Android (Lite Edition), not Google Maps SDK.